# What exactly happens when you change your 3DS region?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

In the 3DS' System settings app, you can try to change your region settings (Country and State/Region). If you attempt to do this, though, a warning is displayed which basically says anything related to the e-Shop won't work any more. Here's the warning:

> If you change your country settings, you will no longer be able to use services that require a Nintendo Network ID, such as browsing Nintendo eShop or posting to Miiverse.

My question is, what exactly will happen if I change that region? Will my 3DS be "disconnected" from my Nintendo Network ID, will my downloaded content disappear/be uninstalled, will I be able to create a new Nintendo Network ID? Will I be able to restore the previous state and connection to my Network ID by changing back to the original region?

**Note that this is not about the market region as in region-lock. This is about the thing you enter when you create your profile for the first time.**

Comment: It says [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/260/~/how-to-change-the-system-region-settings) that only the region you purchased your device in will be listed. What regions do you have listed?

Comment: +1 for the question I can't answer! Excellent question Scenia!

Comment: @Caleb: i don't want to try honestly... But the region mentioned there is the market region, which is either America, Europe or Japan. My current profile region is Germany/Baden-Württemberg and I could have chosen things like France, Italy and Australia (and could change it to those), but I'm too afraid of that warning to try... What the link you posted is saying is that USA, Japan or Mexico won't be listed for me because the system is locked to Europe (which includes Australia oddly enough).

Comment: Here's [more](http://www.vooks.net/upcoming-3ds-update-wont-allow-eshop-region-changes-registering-nnid/) about the change. It's seems to be currency related. Not sure if that helps any though. One note though. In what I've been reading. It appears that if you do manage to change the region, it will forfeit all the currency tried to the old region.

Comment: I would just leave it how it is. I would assume that Nintendo Network ID would be disconnected because of currency conversion. I highly doubt your content would uninstall but I wouldn't take the chance.

Comment: I contacted Nintendo directly, let's see what they answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I decided to test it. My usual profile settings are USA with no state set. Here are my results after changing my location (called 'Region' in the profile settings, which is confusing) to Argentina - Buenos Aires.

- I was still able to play downloaded titles. Shovel Knight worked fine, but I had to accept a basic terms of use agreement.
- I could not enter the eShop or Pokemon Bank, and they displayed a message saying that the region (location) had been changed, and that it had to be changed back to access those services.
- After changing my region back, I had to accept a terms of use agreement for downloaded Pokemon Bank, but not for Shovel Knight (*Shrug*)
- I was able to connect to any NNID services as though nothing had happened.
- The only thing I didn't try was creating a new NNID. I wasn't sure if I would have to delete the one I have now, but I know for certain that if you delete one you WILL lose all downloaded titles permanently.

**Verdict:** As long as you don't delete your NNID, you can change your location settings as much as you like, and you won't lose your downloaded titles, although you may not be able to use anything that requires your NNID to be logged in from your original location.

Comment: Awesome, so changing it back restores everything. Thank you very much for trying this :)