# Does deleting Nintendo Network ID delete save data?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

My network ID is tied to a different region because I've moved countries since I made it, so I can't buy anything because I have the wrong currency and the only way to change region and currency is to get a new network id.

Will deleting my ID and getting a new one delete my save data for my games?

Comment: "the only way to change region and currency is to get a new network id" - this doesn't sound right, because it seems to contradict http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169496/what-exactly-happens-when-you-change-your-3ds-region

Comment: I guess there's also the question of why change your 3DS region at all? AFAIK, deleting your NNID will not allow you to access any downloaded games. There might be other, more severe downsides as well.